# Distributed logging with JMS and logback

Tags: java, logging, jms, logback

I'm working on a project to combine log data from multiple machines to a single DB.

I have to logging scenarios:

1. usual logging of exceptions and developer logging e.g. a dev turns the level to debug.
2. "Audit" logging. Special scenarios need to be logged in a separate DB with separate structure.

I'm using logback and JMS. "Client" logs to JMS Queue and "Server" reads form queue and writes to DB.

I'm looking for a simple way to distinguish the two types of logs.
What I would like to do is create another log level, e.g. "audit" which I could then check on the "server" side and create our special object structure and write to our separate DB.

However this is not possible in logback. I have considered markers but that means a dev has to explicitly apply a marker. My other option is to have two separate loggers and for the dev to grab the correct logger. That's not quite as elegent as I would like.

I'd like the dev to just do log.debug for debug, log.error for errors and log.audit for audit.

Any advice, any one had to solve a similar issue?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, why not just use [DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/DBAppender.html) and log directly to the database, skipping JMS layer? Logback provides facilities to [log asynchronously](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/AsyncAppender.html) if performance is your concern.

As for filtering, separate logger is the easiest and cleanest way to do this (and then simply filter by logger/category). This approaches emphasizes the fact that these are special logs, not the ordinary application debug. I would even consider wrapping this audit logging in some service/aspect to separate it from business logic.

If you really want to reuse existing loggers, You can use Logback [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) to dispatch and filter events at runtime.

Comment: And if the database is unavailable, what happens? The JMS infrastructure could be unavailable as well, however I've never actually experienced an unplanned JMS outage (in my case TIBCO EMS), but I've seen plenty of unplanned DB outages.

Comment: Thomasz, can you provide a link for how Logback supports asynchronous logging? I can't find any reference to it in their documentation or the JavaDoc. Thanks.

Comment: OMG! Still not done: [LBCORE-92](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCORE-92), [LBCLASSIC-177](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-177)... Editing my answer

Comment: As Tomasz notes, there are many reasons to use JMS instead of JDBC.  I am developing a database-intensive application and using JMS for distributing and lightening the load on my EJB's.

I am interested in a discussion of the original question :)

Comment: Update: [`AsyncAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/AsyncAppender.html) finally released. BTW why the downvote?